# How can I use SQL for the following row to column transformation?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, rows

I've done the research, and most questions deal with the opposite situation (columns to rows). I want to know how , within the MS-Access Query Design environment, I can transform the following sample data from state #1 to state #2.

```
State #1

Row |  Organization | SatelliteLocation1 | SatelliteLocation2 | SatelliteLocation3

001        ABC              1000A                                    1000B               
002        DEF              2000A               2000B                
003        GHI              3000A               3000B    

State #2               

Row |  Organization | SatelliteLocationValues

001        ABC                 1000A      
002        ABC                 1000B
003        DEF                 2000A
003        DEF                 2000B
004        GHI                 3000A
004        GHI                 3000B
```

Please keep in mind that:

1) Yes, there are null values for some columns in state #1.

2) I am using Access 2010.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeking is sometimes called an "unpivot" query. It is the UNION of one subquery for each column:

```sql
    SELECT
        Row,
        Organization,
        SatelliteLocation1 AS SatelliteLocations
    FROM State1
    WHERE SatelliteLocation1 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Row,
        Organization,
        SatelliteLocation2 AS SatelliteLocations
    FROM State1
    WHERE SatelliteLocation2 IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Row,
        Organization,
        SatelliteLocation3 AS SatelliteLocations
    FROM State1
    WHERE SatelliteLocation3 IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Write three different SQL queries to obtain the first two columns and each query a different `SatelliteLocation` field (with null-awareness-checking) and `UNION` the three results.

Answer (score 0):

Cross Apply is a good solution here:

```
-- load test data
declare @YourTable table
    (
    Row char(3),
    Organization char(3),
    SatelliteLocation1 char(5),
    SatelliteLocation2 char(5),
    SatelliteLocation3 char(5)
    )
insert into @YourTable
    values
        ('001','ABC','1000A',NULL,'1000B'),
        ('002','DEF','2000A','2000B',NULL),
        ('003','GHI','3000A','3000B',NULL)

-- return State #2 
select Row,Organization,SatelliteLocationValues
from @YourTable s
    cross apply (
                select SatelliteLocation1 as SatelliteLocationValues union
                select SatelliteLocation2 union
                select SatelliteLocation3
                ) t
where t.SatelliteLocationValues is not null
order by Row
```